# Why C++ returns error when I use my custom constructor in priority queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, comparator> pq;

static bool comparator(pair<int, int> &m, pair<int, int> &n) {
    if (m.second < n.second) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Error:
[image: Error image]

I defined my comparator inside a class, and try to declare the priority queue inside another function in the same class, and the error happens.

Comment: Comparator has to be a type which fit the compare requirement, it cannot be a function: here is how you can easily do it: struct comparator
{
 bool operator() (pair<int, int> &m, pair<int, int> &n) {
  if (m.second < n.second) return true;
  else return false;
 }
};

Comment: make the parameters const references : "const pair<int,int>&" a comparator is not supposed to change the parameters.

Comment: On a side note: `if (m.second < n.second) return true; else return false;` can be simplified to `return (m.second < n.second);`

Answer (score 2):

The third template parameter to `std::priority_queue` is a type.

`comparator` is not a type. It is a function.

But before you can fix this, there are two more problems to fix:

1. types and object must be declared before they are used, and the shown code does not declare `comparator` before using it.
2. comparators must taken their parameters as `const` references, they are not allowed to modify them.

Therefore, your comparator should be:

```cpp
static bool comparator(const pair<int, int> &m, const pair<int, int> &n)
```

Its type is: `bool (*)(const pair<int, int> &, const pair<int, int> &)`

That's what the third parameter to `std::priority_queue` template should be, and then the actual comparator must be passed to the object's constructor, `std::priority_queue` has an overloaded constructor that takes an instance of the comparator as a parameter:

```cpp
static bool comparator(const pair<int, int> &m, const pair<int, int> &n) {
    if (m.second < n.second) return true;
    else return false;
}

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>,
           bool (*)(const pair<int, int> &, const pair<int, int> &)
           > pq{comparator};
```

However, you will discover that most of this is unnecessary, and I showed it only for pedanticty's purposes. `std::priority_queue`'s default comparator template parameter will work just fine, because `std::pair` implements `operator<`:

```cpp
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>> pq{comparator};
```

Comment: OP does not want to compare the whole pair, just `.second`.

Answer (score 2):

The third template argument for template type parameter must be a type, whereas `comparator` is a function. You may get the type of the function with `decltype(&comparator)`.

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, decltype(&comparator)> pq(comparator);
```

The last cppreference example with lambda is very similar to your code https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=86f63b09847ba22e.

Comment: In this situation, you have to pass the actual function to the constructor: `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, decltype(&comparator)> pq(comparator);`